# jquery - how to determine if an Items of now viewable/in the window / below the fold

Tags: jquery

with jquery, what's the best way to determine if an element is below the fold meaning it's also not in the window and not visible to the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume you're referring to whether or not it has been scrolled out of view.

If so, try this:

```
if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('#my_el').offset().top ) {
    // element is in view
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8x4Zd/

*(Click the result panel to test if the targeted element is in view. Then scroll down and repeat.)*

If you want to make sure the *entire* element is in view, then add its `.height()` into the equation.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8x4Zd/1/

```
var win = $(window);
var el = $('#my_el');
var winPos = win.scrollTop() + win.height();
var elPos = el.offset().top + el.height();

if( winPos > elPos ) {
    // element is in view
}
```

Comment: That's very cool. I tried that out. The big issue is that when the element is not in view i do ".addClass('fixed');" which is position fixed, bottom:0. which then makes the func above say the element is in view. so what ends up happening is the item flashes in and out of view. Any thoughts?

Comment: the new facebook messages does this with the post comment box . Have you seen that?

Comment: @AnApprentice: I haven't seen that (I don't have a facebook account.) What event triggers the code that does the `addClass()`? You could perhaps add to the test: `&& !el.hasClass('fixed')`.